# Database-side filtering on constructed not-mapped model column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have a EF code-first model with properties: Id and Prefix (both mapped to database) and FullId (not mapped) defined as

```
FullId => Prefix + "-" + Id.ToString("D4")
```

in C# model. Example FullId is

> ABC-0045 or XER-0001

Now I need to filter on this 
FullId field in database, i.e.

```
db.Entity.Where(x=>x.FullId.Contains(search))
```

But search is not just for ID, but for anything in the model (other columns are omitted, like: name, address, etc.). The where predicate is built dynamically.

To solve this so far I have considered:

1. Materializing FullId into database (cons: duplication of data, need to manually update when prefix changes)
2. Making FullId a computed column, but I dont know how to easily make D4 format in SQL (3)
3. Somehow make this possible inside where (ToString("D4") throws unsupported)
4. Regex split the search string itself (input) to search separately in fields, obviously suboptimal since search can potentially search for other fields as well - there are more searchable columns in the model in reality.

What do you suggest is the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how your `search` may look like, so I assume you are searching for specific full ID values that already match your full ID pattern, like `ABC-0045`.

Therefore a good solution would be to split up the full ID you are searching for and filter on the columns seperately.

```
var prefix = search.Split('-')[0];
var id = search.Split('-')[1];
db.Entity.Where(x => x.Id == id && x.Prefix.Equals(prefix));
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but as I mentioned in the point 4), there are more columns in the database which I need to search through. I have edited the question to make that more obvious. Maybe there just isnt any good way to do this.

Comment: So then please explain the purpose of your `search` a little more. Do you want to implement a fulltext search or what is it?

Comment: Yeas, search variable contains arbitrary data and searches against multiple columns. It is a bit weird use case, agree. I take it that really isnt any good way on how to solve this.